# that word your giving all your attention to

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for "keep in mind"?

> You have to keep in mind that...
>
> Please keep in mind...
>
> We have to keep in mind...

If not, please suggest some alternatives.

Comment: Why do you want a single word? Is "remember" okay?

Comment: If you need single words in future, I'd recommend you consult an online thesaurus. [There's one here](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/keep+in+mind), and you can switch between the thesaurus and dictionary if you want to know the meanings of words you find.

Comment: It need not necessarily be a single word. I was in need of some other alternatives to use for this phrase

Comment: Unless you specify the context in more detail, the question is too broad. Below in a comment you mention "fancy words".  If you need a "fancy" word, you should explain why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase 'keep in mind' can have different meanings. I have differentiated and collected words for you as follows:

> - turn over in one's mind
>
>   > consider, recognize, reckon, acknowledge, cogitate, concede, scrutinize, speculate.
> - think about seriously
>
>   > cherish, ponder, muse-over, imagine, hold, heed.
> - hold on to physically or mentally
>
>   > remember, reminisce, retain, save, retrospect, grasp, posses.

Sources:
 http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/keep+in+mind
 http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/keep%20in%20mind

Comment: Did you get these meanings from somewhere? If so you need to reference them!

Comment: @curiousdannii i just googled them.

Comment: @sam-worthingon You need to [edit] this to add the link to where you got them from or this counts as plagiarism and will be deleted.

Comment: @LittleEva I don't know where this is coming from, I just passed by and found the post ugly, so I edited.

Comment: @LittleEva I'm glad you appreciated. Sam added two links at the end of his post, how could he improve more his sources?

Comment: @Yohann - Source citations for links & block quotes should appear in plain text (due to link-rot) somewhere in the body of the post - all I see now is two unspecified hypertext links.

Comment: @LittleEva i don't see any rules or anything anywhere on this page or on this site saying that the sources should be in plain texts. Do you need the ip address,domain-name,site-admins and all that trivial information too??

Answer (score 3):

Remember ?

"You have to remember that... Please remember.. We have to remember.."

Comment: I think that recall or recollect may be used too

Answer (score 3):

`Remember` is the best fit here.

Depending on the context, other single-word options that could work are:

- You have to [**consider**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/consider)

  > 1.4 Take (something) into account when making a judgement:
- You have to **[heed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/heed)**

  > [WITH OBJECT]
  >   Pay attention to; take notice of:
- You have to [**note**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/note)

  > [WITH OBJECT] 1. Notice or pay particular attention to (something):

Answer (score 2):

You have to be **attentive** ...

> [**attentive**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/attentive) adjective: 1. characterized by or giving attention; observant; ***mindful***. See, the Free Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

The Latin to retain sth from tene:re to hold can have the meaning to remember as in

- I can retain names easily. Pons English Deutsch.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget!

My personal opinion is your idiom is too heavy when it being talk out.
Use "don't forget!" or "remember" or ... to recommend somebody and use "keep in mind" to command somebody to do something which is important.

Comment: What "original idiom"??

Comment: sorry, it's a mistake. I should delete "original" word.